# Will I have all the new resources if I move my vanilla server map to Tekkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I want to upgrade my vanilla MineCraft server to Tekkit server. Is there a way to copy my current map form vanilla server to tekkit server? What I am looking for is a way to keep most of my stuff while regenerating blocks to fit Tekkit crafting needs.

As I understand, that copying map itself to bukkit isn't that difficult, but will the new materials be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally porting a map from vanilla to modded (or just adding mods) won't be a problem (just copy the save folder)

however only newly generated chunks will contain the new resources that the mods add so you will be forced to move to new terrain (or reset the chunks) to quarry out the ores you need for the mods

Comment: It's worth noting that with a pack like Tekkit that dramatically alters the worldgen, newly generated chunks will almost certainly not line up to existing ones properly (you'll see a very obvious line between the new and old areas).  This has also happened with major vanilla updates.  If this bothers you, don't try it - instead consider just importing what you care about in a world editor after generating a new map.

Comment: Thank you, I found both of these answers related. I reconsidered and started anew